# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] - Try to Insert Data

Tags: mysql, pdo, syntax, insert, fatal-error

I read and tried hard for the past two hours to run my code. But i got a syntax error in my sql query, can anyone help me?

My code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `article` (`text`,`headline`,`date`,`author`,`active`) SET (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $headline, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(5, $active, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($stmt->execute()) {  //do something }
```

Fatal error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET ('some text','test headline','2017-09-30','author123',1)'

btw, how can i use php code-tags?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try changing "SET" in your query to "VALUES", your use of "SET" is incorrect in that context.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is incorrect. Check the MySQL documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

When using insert query, you use:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```